# what do u mean by bluetooth chat in android

Tags: java, android

```
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
 private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
  public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
 public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
 public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
 public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
 public static final String TOAST = "toast";
 protected static final String TAG = null;
 protected static final boolean D = false;
 protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 3;
 protected static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 2;
```

what do u mean by all these above statement because i am a beginer in the android

Comment: your question is regarding bluetooth chat i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are constants.

`final` mean that the value is assigned once.

`static` means that the variable is shared between all the instances of the class.

`private`, `public` and `protected` are [access modifiers](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/introduction-to-java-access-modifiers).